# Ajax status 200 invalid json parser error

Tags: ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SearchService.asmx/GetSearchResults",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (dataResult) {
        CreateData(dataResult.d);
    },
    error: function (xhr, msg, error) {
        alert("Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText + error + " " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

I get a parser error when I include it on my site. But this code works fine on a test project
I get invalid json parser error.

Comment: then it is clear that `SearchService.asmx/GetSearchResults` returns invalid json

Comment: inspect the ajax request using your browswer's developer toolbar/firebug. Check what value is returned by the server

Comment: I have a test application with the same server and it works fine but not in my actual application

Comment: The statusText is ok but msg is parsererror

Comment: you need to check the response from the server other wise there is no way to debug it

Comment: OMG .. my head is spinning. what is the problem. pls suggest me something

Comment: on `success`, `console.log(dataResult);` and make sure the output is what you expect. Does the URL receiving the AJAX call have the same domain as the sending URL?

Comment: it doesnt go in success function. It just goes in error. I can see the service method running successfully with 35 items. Its just to do something with the parser. some parser error

Comment: @sly_Chandan Please share your answer. Me too facing the same problem